# Ninject dependency resolver plus runtime objects in constructor

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, ninject

I have a factory that creates child instances of my base class the base class constructor contains interfaces which I want do resolve but also runtime objects (I build them dynamical). How would I solve this with ninject?

It is a MVC application.

my factory:

```
public BaseInstallation GetInstallation(CustomerConfiguration customerConfiguration, CallerConfig callerConfig)
    {
        var resolver = System.Web.Http.GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver;

        switch (customerConfiguration.Type)
        {
           case InstallationType.Tablet:
                return resolver.GetService(typeof(InstallationTablet)) as InstallationTablet;

            case InstallationType.Full:
                return resolver.GetService(typeof(InstallationFull)) as InstallationFull;

            default:
                throw new NotImplementedException("Type not implemented yet in factory");

        }
```

I need to pass both customerconfiguration and callerConfiguration into the InstallationTablet and Full constructors on runtime.

The constructor:

```
  public InstallationTablet(CustomerConfiguration customerConfiguration,CallerConfig callerConfig,IDBConnector dbConnector,IFileService fileService)
        : base(customerConfiguration,callerConfig,dbConnector, fileService)
```

I want to resolve only the interfaces with Ninject at start. Is this possible? or do I have to take my objects out of the constructor?

Comment: Where is the info coming from whether it is a Full or a Tablet installation? Where is the CallerConfig coming from?

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
public static InstallationType GetInstallationType() {
   /* your logic goes here */
}

// Bindings
IBindingRoot.Bind<BaseInstallation>().To<InstallationTablet>()
            .When(ctx => GetInstallationType() == InstallationType.Tablet);


IBindingRoot.Bind<BaseInstallation>().To<InstallationFull>()
            .When(ctx => GetInstallationType() == InstallationType.Full);
```

When you answer my questions (see comment) i will extend the answer.